# htaccess to disable wordpress search domain / ? s = test

Tags: linux, .htaccess, apache2, regex

my wordpress blog get's bombarded with senseless search requests.

htaccess to disable wordpress search domain / ? s = test

[image: senseless wordpress search requests]

the search request is in Korean?

[image: wordpress_senseless_searches_result]

which translates as:

[image: wordpress_senseless_searches_result_translated]

so either its DDoS or SPAM.

the IPs in question are:

host 66.249.64.24
24.64.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-64-24.googlebot.com.

host 66.249.64.26
26.64.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-64-26.googlebot.com.

something is wrong with iptables and i can not block the requests via IP.

the requests look like this:

```
domain.com/?s=StrangeKoreanSearchPattern
```

what regex would i need in .htaccess to make all searchs password protected?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "WordPress Admin"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

# DOES NOT WORK :-|    
<FilesMatch "index\.php\?s=.*">
    AuthName "WordPress Admin"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you need to block _all requests_ that contain the query string `s=<something>` or just `s=<Korean-something>` (or non-English language)? Are you wanting to block these requests for all users, or trigger a password dialog (as in your example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a litte bit of research and testing I would say following htaccess entry should work:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.?s=/">
  AuthName "WordPress Admin"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903448/htaccess-deny-specific-get-parameter

To clarify what this is doing:
If the Query String (the string that begins with "?" after "domain.com/") contains "?s=", then require a valid user from the .htpasswd file.

Comment: realized there is another way to trigger wordpress search: domain.com/?search=bla should be covered by another <If statement with: <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.?search=/"> thanks! apache is holding the world record on complicated software https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: argh: the regex also triggers on domain.com/wp-json/shariff/v1/share_counts?url=coolArticleUrl

Comment: What is the reason for the `.?` part in your regex? (It's not doing anything.)

Comment: The  dot was my fault. It should have been a backslash. The backslash would escape the question mark and the regex result would excactly be `?s=` .

Comment: @canoodle i have no idea why it triggers on domain.com/wp-json/shariff/v1/share_counts?url=coolArticleUrl. Does this url contain `s=` anywhere?

Comment: @r00tusr "It should have been a backslash. The backslash would escape the question mark..." - That would certainly have been an _error_, since the `QUERY_STRING` server variable does not actually contain the `?` (question mark) that delimits the query string - so it would _never_ have matched.

Comment: @MrWhite ah ok, thank you for that info. I have never worked with 'QUERY_STRING' and I didn't find anything about that question mark.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your answer, .htaccess and regex are two beasts in one.

modified your answer and it seems to work fine now. #Thanks!

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^.?s=/">
  AuthName "WordPress Admin"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>

<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^.?search=/">
  AuthName "WordPress Admin"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: No need for two blocks (and that `.?` bit would seem to be superfluous?)... it's a regex, so you can combine the two. For example: `/^(s|search)=/`